# Better way of joining 1 column to one of 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have to join a single ID column to either 1 of two different tables.  I know which one to go to based on an column called reqIdType that tells me which type of ID the reqID column contains.  This is what I'm doing:

```
SELECT e.*,
reqfirstName =
CASE e.reqIDtype
    WHEN 'N' THEN
        u1.firstName
    ELSE c1.firstName
END,
reqLastName =
CASE e.reqIDtype
    WHEN 'N' THEN
        u1.lastName
    ELSE c1.lastName
END
repeat with email, etc.
FROM ers e
LEFT JOIN contacts c1 ON c.contactID = e.reqID
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON u1.uid = reqID
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?  Somehow where I could check the reqIDType field and then select all my fields, else select all my other fields?  The way I'm doing it now is making a lot of messy SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that you have two disjoint sets: ERs associated with contacts and ERs associated with users. You can select each set separately and simply append the results:

```
SELECT e.*, u.firstName, u.lastName /* etc.. */
FROM ers e JOIN users u ON u.uid = e.reqID
WHERE e.reqIDtype = 'N'
UNION ALL
SELECT e.*, c.firstName, c.lastName /* etc.. */
FROM ers e JOIN contacts c ON c.contactID = e.reqID
WHERE e.reqIDtype <> 'N'
```

Comment: That is another way of doing it for sure.  My where clause is huge with a lot of complicated logic that I would have to duplicate though.

Comment: Try dropping the above into a view, rewrite your query and where clause in terms to use it, and see if the conditions are taken into the inner queries or not. Or use "WITH" to produce a set of ers.reqID values as a CTE and reference that twice instead of [ers] directly.